# xamgrid celldoubleclicked event- Silverlight MVVM

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0

> I have a xamgrid and I need to call my viewmodel command to perform some action when user >double click on xamgrid cell(event: celldoubleclicked). How to handle this scenario with >MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the EventToCommand trigger from [MvvmLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

```
<ig:XamGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellDoubleClicked">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command={Binding MyCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ig:XamGrid>
```

Or the InvokeCommandAction in the Blend sdk:

```
<ig:XamGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellDoubleClicked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command={Binding MyCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ig:XamGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks Alyce for the reply but can't we avoid third party? as I am new to mvvm.

Comment: You could, but you would have to rewrite a pretty robust, solid and easy to use framework. I think you'll find it's not that much of a learning curve, and there is heaps of help online (in fact, most MVVM walkthroughs include MvvmLight).

Comment: Just remembered the InvokeCommandAction in the same namespace as the EventTrigger, updating my answer...

Comment: Thanks Alyce, I followed MvvmLight binaries. Is mvvmLight need to be registered later? And if I want to use the same command with two different flags, can we make use of commandparamtervalue using eventtocommand?

Comment: What do you mean by registered? Yes, you can use a CommandParameter with EventToCommand.